# Optimistic update VS invalidatesTags in RTK Query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have a simple code sampel from RTK query docs:

```
updatePost: build.mutation<void, Pick<Post, 'id'> & Partial<Post>>({
  query: ({ id, ...patch }) => ({
    url: `posts/${id}`,
    method: 'PUT',
    body: patch,
  }),
  async onQueryStarted({ id, ...patch }, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
    const patchResult = dispatch(
      api.util.updateQueryData('getPost', id, (draft) => {
        Object.assign(draft, patch)
      })
    )
    try {
      await queryFulfilled
    } catch {
      patchResult.undo()
    }
  },
  invalidatesTags: (result, error, { id }) => [{ type: 'Post', id }],
}),
```

If I remove `async onQueryStarted` the update appears to be still working. However, if I remove `invalidatesTags` and keep only `async onQueryStarted`, it does not work without refreshing the application.

**Question**: why should I use also `async onQueryStarted` even if `invalidatesTags` appears to be working fine? Why it is suggested to use BOTH `invalidatesTags` and `async onQueryStarted` in official docs?

Answer (score 0):

It is not suggested anywhere that you have to use both. Some people really want optimistic updates, and they can use them. For most users, automated tag-based refetching should be enough.